# Replicating file to remote server, Issue while joining path of local and remote server copying files in powershell

Tags: powershell

`enter code here`I am facing issue while replicating files to remote server, joining the path failing somehow.
Below is code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteServer -ScriptBlock {param($DestinationDir,$LocalCertResultObj,$RemoteCertResultObj,$SourceDir) Compare-Object $LocalCertResultObj $RemoteCertResultObj  -Property Name, Length, FullName   | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | ForEach-Object {
        {$DestinationDir = Join-Path $DestinationDir $_.FullName.Substring($SourceDir.length)}
        Write-Output $DestinationDir
        Write-Output $SourceDir
      Copy-Item -Path "$SourceDir\$($_.name)" -Destination "$DestinationDir" -Recurse -Force
}   } -ArgumentList $DestinationDir,$LocalCertResultObj,$RemoteCertResultObj,$SourceDir -Credential $RemoteMachine_cred
```

Getting error like below:

```
$DestinationDir = Join-Path $DestinationDir $_.FullName.Substring($SourceDir.length)
C:\TestFolderR
C:\TestFolder
Cannot find path 'C:\TestFolder\file1.txt' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\TestFolder\file1.txt:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining the path looks to be working fine. [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1)'s error is pretty clear that it can't find `C:\TestFolder\file1.txt`. Since you're presumably trying to copy this file to the remote server, your `ScriptBlock` used with [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command?view=powershell-5.1) is going to run that entire [`ScriptBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-5.1) on the remote system. It's not going to be able to copy that file over the PowerShell session because it's not aware of your local filesystem - at least, not by using `Invoke-Command`.

You can establish a [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-5.1) to the remote system, and use this with `Copy-Item` directly from your local session to the remote filesystem:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName server.domain.tld -Credential $RemoteMachine_Cred
Copy-Item -ToSession $Session -Path $localPath-Destination $remotePath
```

---

You can even copy an item from the remote filesystem back to your local system, too. Using the same `$Session` we established above:

```
Copy-Item -FromSession $Session -Path $remotePath -Destination $localPath
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tried your solution, getting below error now:$DestinationDir = Join-Path $DestinationDir $_.FullName.Substring($SourceDir.length)
Cannot bind parameter 'ToSession'. Cannot convert the "[PSSession]WinRM13" value of type "Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession" to type
"System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession".

Comment: How and where are you invoking Copy-Item with the session variable?